# REST User registration and Login through Api Key

Tags: codeigniter, rest, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-restserver

I am not new to codeignitor , but still i didn't used they feature called 'API keys' authentication.

What i want to do ?

- Register a user in `my_users` table and there is `apikey` as column that should store and generate unique api while user registration.
- Login User , user give username , password and it get response as logged in if correct information is given , with it's respective `apikey` in `my_users` table.
- After login i want to use apikey for all other user related calls like `bookATask` with header as `X-API-KEY` , which will allow me to control user session at client side and secure login and sign system.

Problem in Setup:

- I am being asked each time i make a request to pass `X-API-KEY` which is wrong because , maybe there is call `register_post` in `User` controller which register users and Api key cannot be passed in headers unless it is generated in this method right?
- I am just getting status:FALSE and error:`Invalid Api key` on each call i make.

What am i doing?

**(Only changed code)**

**application/config/rest.php**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config['force_https'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_default_format'] = 'json';
$config['rest_supported_formats'] = [
    'json',
    'array',
    'csv',
    'html',
    'jsonp',
    'php',
    'serialized',
    'xml',
];
$config['rest_status_field_name'] = 'status';
$config['rest_message_field_name'] = 'error';
$config['enable_emulate_request'] = TRUE;
$config['rest_realm'] = 'REST API';
$config['rest_auth'] = 'basic';
$config['auth_source'] = '';
$config['allow_auth_and_keys'] = TRUE;
$config['auth_library_class'] = '';
$config['auth_library_function'] = '';
$config['auth_override_class_method_http']['user']['register']['post'] = 'none';
$config['auth_override_class_method_http']['user']['login']['post'] = 'none';
$config['rest_valid_logins'] = ['user1' => '12345'];
$config['rest_ip_whitelist_enabled'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_ip_whitelist'] = '';
$config['rest_ip_blacklist_enabled'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_ip_blacklist'] = '';
$config['rest_database_group'] = 'default';
$config['rest_keys_table'] = 'my_users';
$config['rest_enable_keys'] = TRUE;
$config['rest_key_column'] = 'apikey';
$config['rest_limits_method'] = 'ROUTED_URL';
$config['rest_key_length'] = 40;
$config['rest_key_name'] = 'X-API-KEY';
$config['rest_enable_logging'] = TRUE;
$config['rest_logs_table'] = 'app_logs';
$config['rest_enable_access'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_access_table'] = 'access';
$config['rest_logs_json_params'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_enable_limits'] = TRUE;
$config['rest_limits_table'] = 'app_limits';
$config['rest_ignore_http_accept'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_ajax_only'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_language'] = 'english';
$config['check_cors'] = FALSE;
$config['allowed_cors_headers'] = [
  'Origin',
  'X-Requested-With',
  'Content-Type',
  'Accept',
  'Access-Control-Request-Method'
];
$config['allowed_cors_methods'] = [
  'GET',
  'POST',
  'OPTIONS',
  'PUT',
  'PATCH',
  'DELETE'
];
$config['allow_any_cors_domain'] = FALSE;
$config['allowed_cors_origins'] = [];
```

**application/config/autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

**controllers/api/Key.php**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
class Key extends REST_Controller {

    protected $methods = [
            'index_put' => ['level' => 10, 'limit' => 10],
            'index_delete' => ['level' => 10],
            'level_post' => ['level' => 10],
            'regenerate_post' => ['level' => 10],
        ];
    public function index_put()
    {
        $key = $this->_generate_key();
        $level = $this->put('level') ? $this->put('level') : 1;
        $ignore_limits = ctype_digit($this->put('ignore_limits')) ? (int) $this->put('ignore_limits') : 1;
        if ($this->_insert_key($key, ['level' => $level, 'ignore_limits' => $ignore_limits]))
        {
            $this->response([
                'status' => TRUE,
                'key' => $key
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED); // CREATED (201) being the HTTP response code
        }
        else
        {
            $this->response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'message' => 'Could not save the key'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); // INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR (500) being the HTTP response code
        }
    }
    public function index_delete()
    {
        $key = $this->delete('key');
        if (!$this->_key_exists($key))
        {
            $this->response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'message' => 'Invalid API key'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST); // BAD_REQUEST (400) being the HTTP response code
        }
        $this->_delete_key($key);
        $this->response([
            'status' => TRUE,
            'message' => 'API key was deleted'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NO_CONTENT); // NO_CONTENT (204) being the HTTP response code
    }
    public function level_post()
    {
        $key = $this->post('key');
        $new_level = $this->post('level');
        if (!$this->_key_exists($key))
        {
            $this->response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'message' => 'Invalid API key'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST); // BAD_REQUEST (400) being the HTTP response code
        }
        if ($this->_update_key($key, ['level' => $new_level]))
        {
            $this->response([
                'status' => TRUE,
                'message' => 'API key was updated'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); // OK (200) being the HTTP response code
        }
        else
        {
            $this->response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'message' => 'Could not update the key level'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); // INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR (500) being the HTTP response code
        }
    }
    public function suspend_post()
    {
        $key = $this->post('key');
        if (!$this->_key_exists($key))
        {
            $this->response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'message' => 'Invalid API key'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST); // BAD_REQUEST (400) being the HTTP response code
        }
        if ($this->_update_key($key, ['level' => 0]))
        {
            $this->response([
                'status' => TRUE,
                'message' => 'Key was suspended'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); // OK (200) being the HTTP response code
        }
        else
        {
            $this->response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'message' => 'Could not suspend the user'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); // INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR (500) being the HTTP response code
        }
    }
    public function regenerate_post()
    {
        $old_key = $this->post('key');
        $key_details = $this->_get_key($old_key);
        if (!$key_details)
        {
            $this->response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'message' => 'Invalid API key'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST); // BAD_REQUEST (400) being the HTTP response code
        }
        $new_key = $this->_generate_key();
        if ($this->_insert_key($new_key, ['level' => $key_details->level, 'ignore_limits' => $key_details->ignore_limits]))
        {
            $this->_update_key($old_key, ['level' => 0]);

            $this->response([
                'status' => TRUE,
                'key' => $new_key
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED); // CREATED (201) being the HTTP response code
        }
        else
        {
            $this->response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'message' => 'Could not save the key'
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); // INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR (500) being the HTTP response code
        }
    }
    private function _generate_key()
    {
        do
        {
            $salt = base_convert(bin2hex($this->security->get_random_bytes(64)), 16, 36);
            if ($salt === FALSE)
            {
                $salt = hash('sha256', time() . mt_rand());
            }

            $new_key = substr($salt, 0, config_item('rest_key_length'));
        }
        while ($this->_key_exists($new_key));

        return $new_key;
    }
    private function _get_key($key)
    {
        return $this->db
            ->where(config_item('rest_key_column'), $key)
            ->get(config_item('rest_keys_table'))
            ->row();
    }

    private function _key_exists($key)
    {
        return $this->db
            ->where(config_item('rest_key_column'), $key)
            ->count_all_results(config_item('rest_keys_table')) > 0;
    }

    private function _insert_key($key, $data)
    {
        $data[config_item('rest_key_column')] = $key;
        $data['date_created'] = function_exists('now') ? now() : time();

        return $this->db
            ->set($data)
            ->insert(config_item('rest_keys_table'));
    }

    private function _update_key($key, $data)
    {
        return $this->db
            ->where(config_item('rest_key_column'), $key)
            ->update(config_item('rest_keys_table'), $data);
    }

    private function _delete_key($key)
    {
        return $this->db
            ->where(config_item('rest_key_column'), $key)
            ->delete(config_item('rest_keys_table'));
    }

}
```

**(Method used in controller to generate Api key)**

```
private function _generate_key()
    {
    do
    {
        // Generate a random salt
        $salt = base_convert(bin2hex($this->security->get_random_bytes(64)), 16, 36);

        // If an error occurred, then fall back to the previous method
        if ($salt === FALSE)
        {
            $salt = hash('sha256', time() . mt_rand());
        }

        $new_key = substr($salt, 0, config_item('rest_key_length'));
    }
    while ($this->_key_exists($new_key));

    return $new_key;
    }

    private function _key_exists($key)
    {
    return $this->db
        ->where(config_item('rest_key_column'), $key)
        ->count_all_results(config_item('rest_keys_table')) > 0;
    }
```

On Database i have two extra tables `app_limits` , `app_logs` , and `apikey` column with varchar(40) in `my_users` table that's all , can anyone help me solving my issue , what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer myself , i just modifying these variables helped me :

```
$config['auth_override_class_method_http']['user']['customer_register']['post'] = 'none';
$config['auth_override_class_method_http']['user']['customer_login']['post'] = 'none';
```

these are basically exception methods for Api key which can be register and login , thanks myself

Comment: Hi @zulqurnain-jutt ... I'm working with CI and the REST API with something very very close to your project and seems that you have figured out how it works. 
Can I pick your brain a little bit, there are a couple of things in the authentication that I'm missing out.

Comment: this is what I am using: $config['auth_override_class_method_http']['admin']['auth']['post'] = 'none'; but its not working for me. is it because I am using HMVC?